# How to convert charater date column with two different date formats to date data type

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I'm new to R programming and currently working on a data frame, which is imported from a .csv file that has a "Date" column. This columns consists of two different date format (dd/mm/yyyy & mm/dd/yyyy) such as this:
[Image One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liy2A.png)

Then I went ahead and attempted to convert them all, which as of right now is a **character** type, to **date** data type with the following code:

```
test$Date <- as.Date(test$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

The above code certainly works, and now the "Date" column is now converted to **date** type but some of the dates appear to be missing due to some kind of problem after running the code: [Image Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDHwj.png)

I have no idea what's the issue here and would like to ask if anyone knows how to fix it. I would appreciate all the help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it is not possible the way you want to do it!

The closest function I have in mind is `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` package which makes use of `guess_formats` function:

```
library(lubridate)

string_date <- c("29/02/2020", "7/01/2020")
string_date


parse_date_time(string_date, c("dmY", "mdY"))

# gives:
# [1] "2020-02-29 UTC" "2020-01-07 UTC"
```

And I don't think that two different date formats in one column as class date are possible.

So try to clean up your data and make two different columns or flag your class character column!

Answer (score 1):

This is a real life mess where you have messy data - merged two date formats in 1 column.

1. Please see if you can make both to same format : either dmy or ymd
   2 OR if you can identify thsoe with some other data column? (For example some other variable which can help you identify which records have dmy and which has mdy
2. If 2nd is possible, mutate the date column conditionally or use case_when.

OR : in try in 2 passes (or as many formats) :
Apply lubridate: dmy() first and then apply ymd() where results are NA in first pass.

Example: Here sourced from A is dd/mm/yyyy and B are mm/dd/yyyy :

```
a <- data.frame(dates = c('02/01/2020','02/04/2020','02/06/2020',
                     '12/31/2020','11/21/2020')
           ,Sourced = c('A','A','A','B','B'))
```

First pass :

```
b <- a%>%
  mutate(Clean_Date1 = dmy(dates))

       dates Sourced Clean_Date1
1 02/01/2020       A  2020-01-02
2 02/04/2020       A  2020-04-02
3 02/06/2020       A  2020-06-02
4 12/31/2020       B        <NA>
5 11/21/2020       B        <NA>
```

Now using this :

```
b%>%
  mutate(Clean_Date2 = if_else(is.na(Clean_Date1),mdy(dates),Clean_Date1))

       dates Sourced Clean_Date1 Clean_Date2
1 02/01/2020       A  2020-01-02  2020-01-02
2 02/04/2020       A  2020-04-02  2020-04-02
3 02/06/2020       A  2020-06-02  2020-06-02
4 12/31/2020       B        <NA>  2020-12-31
5 11/21/2020       B        <NA>  2020-11-21
```

Hope this gives some ideas as final column is all in same date format:

```
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ dates      : chr  "02/01/2020" "02/04/2020" "02/06/2020" "12/31/2020" ...
 $ Sourced    : chr  "A" "A" "A" "B" ...
 $ Clean_Date1: Date, format: "2020-01-02" "2020-04-02" "2020-06-02" ...
 $ Clean_Date2: Date, format: "2020-01-02" "2020-04-02" "2020-06-02" ...
```